# Write a function in R to change a group of datasets layout

Tags: r, function

I have many datasets in tibble format, with variables as rows. I want to change the layout and wrangle individual dataset. To save myself from repetitive work and risk of making mistakes. I wrote this function in **R** to do this.

```
library(tidyverse)    
change_data_layout<- function(data_df){    
data_df_2 <- data_df %>% mutate(samples = colnames()) %>% t()    
colnames(data_df_2) <-data_df_2[1,]    
rownames <- rownames(data_df_2) [2:nrow(data_df_2)]

data_df_3 <- data_df_2[1:nrow(data_df_2),] %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate(samples = rownames)    
colnames(data_df_3) <- data_df_3 [1,]    
data_df_4 <- data_df_3[2:nrow(data_df_3),]

data_final <- data_df_4 %>% 
mutate_each(funs(type.convert)) %>%  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)        

return(data_final)
}
```

However, when I run this function as :

```
dataset1_final <- change_data_layout(dataset1)
```

I got this error message:

> **Error: argument "x" is missing, with no default
>
>       Called from: mutate_impl(.data, dots)**

Any help and suggestions?

Comment: The error indicates that a function was called without a required argument, and that the source was within a mutate. Perhaps `colnames()`?

Comment: as @Damian said. You have `colnames()` without an argument. If you are wanting to use `colnames(data_df)`, you will also have issues.  You should post a portion of your `dataset1` with `dput(dataset1)`, as well as posting desired results.